# Using an Enum inside a Class as a Function parameter outside of its Class

Tags: c++, windows, class, enums

I have an Enum that I already use for multiple other purposes, however in those cases I use the Enum like a public variable of the class meaning I can access it like `EntityManager.FAll`.
However, in the new use case I have for it I want to use the Enum in that class as a function parameter of another class's function like `CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes`.

But no matter what I try, when I try to compile the code this always fails telling me that either when using the scope operator I need to be using a Class or Namespace even though this is a class (error code: C2653), or that `EBroadcastTypes` isnt a known identifier (error code: 2061).

Just to further 'visualize' this, as an example.
I want to use this Enum for 'filtering channels' when Ray Casting, so that I can either only check for specific Wanted Entities.

```
EntityManager.h

class CEntityManager
{
public:

    CEntityManager();

    ~CEntityManager();

private:
    // Prevent use of copy constructor and assignment operator (private and not defined)
    CEntityManager( const CEntityManager& );
    CEntityManager& operator=( const CEntityManager& );


/////////////////////////////////////
//  Public interface
public:

    enum EBroadcastTypes
    {
        FAll,
        FTank,
        FShell,
        FDynamic, // Any Entity that can movement on update (ie. Tank and Shells)
        FStatic, // Any Entity that never moves (ie. Enivronment)
    };

    struct BroadcastFilter
    {
        EBroadcastTypes type;
        vector<string> channels;
    };

    vector<BroadcastFilter> m_BroadcastFilters;

    vector<string> GetChannelsOfFilter(EBroadcastTypes Type)
    {
        for (const auto& BroadcastFilter : m_BroadcastFilters)
        {
            if (BroadcastFilter.type == Type)
            {
                return BroadcastFilter.channels;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

```
ProjectName.cpp

#include "EntityManager.h"
#include "CRayCasting.h"

CEntityManager EntityManager;

// Primary Update(tick) function
Update()
{
   if(true)// On Some condition
   {
      TFloat32 range = 400.0f
      CRay ray;
      ray.m_Origin = CVector3(0,0,0);
      ray.m_Direction = CVector3(0,0,0);
      HitResult Hit = RayCast(ray, EntityManager.FAll, range);
   
      // Do something with Hit ...  
   }
}
```

RayCast file doesn't contain a class, simply functions that fall under the same category that would be used across multiple points/classes throughout the code.

```
CRayCasting.h

#include "EntityManager.h"

class CEntity;

struct HitResult
{
    CVector3 m_hitPosition;
    CEntity* m_hitEntity;
};

struct CRay
{
    CVector3 m_Origin;
    CVector3 m_Direction;
};

// Simple RayCast, checking intersection with any Entity,
// Checks against all entities that belong to this Channel.
HitResult RayCast(CRay ray, CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes WantedChannel); // This is line 50 in the output/error messages
```

```
CRayCasting.cpp

#include "CRayCasting.h"

// Get Access to the Entity Manager
extern CEntityManager EntityManager;

// Simple RayCast, checking intersection with any Entity - Checks whether entity is of wanted Type/Channel
HitResult RayCast(CRay ray, CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes WantedChannel)
{
    HitResult closestIntersection;

    vector<string> channels = EntityManager.GetChannelsOfFilter(static_cast<CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes>(WantedChannel));

    // Do the Raycast

    return closestIntersection;
}
```

So is there any way to actually use the Enum like this?

Tried including the header as well as forward declaring both the class and enum (the compiler then told me it didn't know what those forwards are).

**EDIT:**
I accidentally used the wrong operator (. instead of ::) for when calling the RayCast function, as I wrote the question.
But this isnt even where the compiler gives me an error.
The error happens inside the header file at the function declaration.

The error codes here as well with better formating:

```
Error C2653 'CEntityManager': is not a class or namespace name ProjectName E:\Project\Source\Physics\CRayCasting.h 50
```

```
Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'EBroadcastTypes' ProjectName E:\Project\Source\Physics\CRayCasting.h 50
```

**EDIT 2:**
As suggested I included pretty much everything of the code relevant to the use of the enum from that class in my function. If there is anything missing to count this as MRE please let me know, my first time doing this.
Additionally added the compiler output as suggested (Not sure if I should do the whole thing or only relevant parts, but here is everything for now):
https://pastebin.com/Sjyg5nKw

Comment: Offtopic: By reading between lines I see `using namespace std;` in a header file! This is big mistake! Do not do that.

Comment: Please don't paraphrase the errors. Copy and paste them verbatim into your question, so we can see for ourselves what is the problem, as they usually contain all the necessary information to fix them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated the parameter 'Type' I forgot to add, maybe you meant this?

Comment: `EntityManager.FAll` -> `CEntityManager::FAll`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Didnt want to spam with a massive message.

Here is the errors:

Error C2653 'CEntityManager': is not a class or namespace name TankAssignment E:\Project\Source\Physics\CRayCasting.h 50  

Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'EBroadcastTypes' ProjectName E:\Project\Source\Physics\CRayCasting.h 50

Comment: @MarekR Yes you are right, thats how I usually access the Enum values as well. I just mistakenly used the wrong operator when writing the quesiton. Will update post now.

Comment: We don't see line 50 in `CRayCasting.h` so we can't see the syntax error you are asking about

Comment: Side note: In Visual Studio the best way to get the diagnostic messages is from the Output tab normally found beside the Error List tab. You get the full and un-summarized diagnostic in plain text that formats nicely into a Stack Overflow Question. Plus the extra information in the non-summarized diagnostic sometimes tells you exactly what you needed to know.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the Declaration of the function is line 50.
Sorry know thats not obvious, but didnt want to C/P the entire code file in here since I thought it would make everything bloated and less readable.

Comment: @Neuffexx We don't need the full code, but a [mre]. Did you mislabel `CRayCasting.h` when you wrote `CRayCast.h` in the question?

Comment: A `;` is missing from the end of `CEntityManager.h`.

Comment: `GetChannelsOfFilter` doesn't return a value in all paths, but other than that, [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/cMMfEM71e), so there is something you are not showing us.

Comment: As written by @Neuffexx, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) + the full error output of your compiler. Don't make any code edits after copy-pasting the code, because your edits, by accident, may be hiding the reason of the error; and also line numbers in the error message should correspond to the code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I did will update now..

Comment: @Neuffexx As I showed, the code you've presented will not cause the compilation error you get. There is something you are not showing us. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Got it, ill will try to include any relevant code, just removing the bloat that isnt actually used in this usecase.

Comment: Are you really including a *source* file (`#include "CRayCast.cpp"`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No? Did I write that somehwere by accident? I dont see it.
But if your asking about my actual code and not the post, then no. I never include .cpp files like that. (dont even know if there is a viable use for doing that)

Comment: If I copy the code you've presented, it will not produce the error you claim to get. I get tons of other errors, but not that.

Comment: @Neuffexx Your newer edits have fixed that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Enumerations are members of the *class* in C++, not any specific object (they are in essence static).

Because of this you need to use the class-name and the scope operator `::` to access the enumeration values. As in

```
RayCast(ray, CEntityManager::FAll, range);
```

Comment: I edited the post to clarify a bit, as I messed up when riting it.
But the error isnt because of this, as I do exactly the same thing as you suggested, it occurs in the header file.

Comment: @Neuffexx Let me then ***guess*** (because you don't show a [mre]): In `EntityManager.h` do you include `CRayCasting.h`?

Answer (score 0):

As written in comments and other answers, use `CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes` as the enum type, and use `CEntityManager::FAll` etc. as enum values.

This compiles for me without warnings:

```
// EntityManager.h
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class CEntityManager
{
   public:

   enum EBroadcastTypes
   {
    FAll,
    FVehicle,
    FProjectile,
    FDynamic, // Any Entity that can movement on update (ie. Vehicle and Shells)
    FStatic,  // Any Entity that never moves (ie. Scenery)
   };

   struct BroadcastFilter
   {
    EBroadcastTypes type;
    std::vector<std::string> channels;
   };

   std::vector<BroadcastFilter> m_BroadcastFilters;

   std::vector<std::string> GetChannelsOfFilter(EBroadcastTypes Type)
   {
    for (const auto& BroadcastFilter : m_BroadcastFilters)
    {
        if (BroadcastFilter.type == Type)
        {
            return BroadcastFilter.channels;
        }
    }
   }
};
```

```
// CRayCast.cpp
#include "EntityManager.h"

struct CRay {};
typedef float TFloat32;
typedef int HitResult;

HitResult RayCast(CRay, CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes Type, TFloat32) {
  return Type == CEntityManager::FAll ? 5 : 6;
}
```

Compile command: `g++ -std=c++11 -c -O2 -W -Wall CRayCast.cpp`

Comment: Updated the post, I accidentally used the wrong opperator when writing it.
When doing this I get the errors I mentioned in the Edit note.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors for the code in my answer. If you are getting errors for your code, then your code is substantially different from the code in my answer. To fix it, start with code in my answer, check that it compiles, replace a fragment, check again etc.

Answer (score 0):

So after getting in touch with someone more experienced than me, he guessed it might be a hidden circular dependency issue.

So we moved the enum out of the class and made it into an enum class.
Then forward declared the enum class, rather than what I previously tried which was the enum directly as it was still a part of the EntityManager class (enum CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes;).

Means I need to change the use of the enum as well for example in the `ProjectName.cpp` from `EntityManager.Fall` to `EBroadcastTypes::Fall`.

So the result, to put it into code, is:

```
EntityManager.h

enum class EBroadcastTypes
    {
        FAll,
        FTank,
        FShell,
        FDynamic, // Any Entity that can movement on update (ie. Tank and Shells)
        FStatic, // Any Entity that never moves (ie. Enivronment)
    };

class CEntityManager
{
public:

    CEntityManager();

    ~CEntityManager();

private:
    // Prevent use of copy constructor and assignment operator (private and not defined)
    CEntityManager( const CEntityManager& );
    CEntityManager& operator=( const CEntityManager& );


/////////////////////////////////////
//  Public interface
public:

    struct BroadcastFilter
    {
        EBroadcastTypes type;
        vector<string> channels;
    };

    vector<BroadcastFilter> m_BroadcastFilters;

    vector<string> GetChannelsOfFilter(EBroadcastTypes Type)
    {
        for (const auto& BroadcastFilter : m_BroadcastFilters)
        {
            if (BroadcastFilter.type == Type)
            {
                return BroadcastFilter.channels;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

```
CRayCasting.h

#include "EntityManager.h"

class CEntity;
enum class EBroadcastTypes;

struct HitResult
{
    CVector3 m_hitPosition;
    CEntity* m_hitEntity;
};

struct CRay
{
    CVector3 m_Origin;
    CVector3 m_Direction;
};

// Simple RayCast, checking intersection with any Entity,
// Checks against all entities that belong to this Channel.
HitResult RayCast(CRay ray, CEntityManager::EBroadcastTypes WantedChannel);
```